# C++ map/unordered_map char* as key

Tags: c++

Hello Iḿ trying to write a simple web server... this is my HTTP class constructor in which I parse the response, more specific the l variable which contains METHOD PATH HTTPVERSION (ex. GET / HTTP/1.1), I then pass the m variable that stands for method into the map_methods function but I can´t get it to return the correct ENUM value; but If I pass a literal "GET" or "POST" it does work... any one have any clue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <map>
#include "http.h"

using std::map;

Http::Http(char *request)
{
    char *l, *h, *k, *m, *p, *t, *v;

    if (!strlen(request))
        goto err;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(request) - 1; i++)
        if (request[i] == '\n' == request[i + 1])
            request[i + 1] = '|';

    l = strtok(request, "\n");
    h = strtok(__null, "|");
    k = strtok(__null, "|");

    m = strtok(l, " ");
    p = strtok(__null, " ");
    t = strtok(__null, " ");
    v = strtok(t, "HTTP/");

    this->uri = p;
    this->version = (float)atof(v);
    this->method = this->map_methods(m);

    return;
err:
{
    perror("Error parsing request");
    exit(1);
}
}

int Http::map_methods(const char *m)
{
    printf("%s\n", m);
    map<const char *, int> methods = {
        {"GET", GET},
        {"POST", POST},
        {"PUT", PUT},
        {"HEAD", HEAD},
        {"PATCH", PATCH},
        {"DELETE", DELETE},
        {"CONNECT", CONNECT},
        {"OPTIONS", OPTIONS},
        {"TRACE", TRACE},
    };
    printf("%i\n", methods[m]);
    return methods[m];
}
```

EDIT:
If anyone stumbles in here by accident then this is the solution...

```
struct strcmp_s
{
    bool operator()(char const *s1, char const *s2) const
    {
        return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
    }
};
```

and pass it to map as `std::map<const char *,int, strcmp_s>`

How ever you can make this work, without changing anything using

```
std::map<std::string,int>
```

EDIT:EDIT:

Was no satisfied with any of the answers on this nor on the other post so decided to dig a little deeper.
The string compare structure works fine for the `std::map` but things get a little bit harder when trying to implement `std::unordered_map`.
One might be inclined to pursue and dig deeper into the path of implementing their own hash and/or their own key compare functions for that matter.

Yet somehow these solutions feel off-topic and the question of how to implement an map/unordered_map with `char *` key remains without answer.

I'm new to C++ but feel like the response of using `std::string` and replacing completely `char *` is overly shared; and almost never fitting;
like asking for chocolate-chips and getting oatmeal-raisin.

That being said; Please correct me if I'm wrong and please feel free to add since what C version; `std::string_view` is the way to go. Works with both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` out of the box.

Following templates can be easily used;

```
#include <string_view>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename T>
using dic = std::map<std::string_view, T>

template <typename T>
using unordered_dic = std::unordered_map<std::string_view, T>;
```

Comment: The duplicate explains how to patch the problem keeping `const char*` as keys, but is there any reason why you create this weird mix of C and C++ in the first place? Making it `std::map<std::string, EnumType>` would make it work out of the box, no need for weird `char*` machinations.

Comment: What is `__null`? Why don't you use `std::string` for all your strings? Why do you convert the `float` result of `atof` to a `float` (and bearing in mind that almost all C-style conversions should be considered wrong, and that `atof` have very little to no validation)? Why are you using the type-unsafe C function `printf`?

Comment: As for your problem, TL;DR: When you have a pointer as a key, it's the ***pointer*** that is the key, not the object or data it might point to.

Comment: thank you for the comments, suggestions and reference to the other ticket...

Comment: You can self-answer your question. Do not integrate the answer into the question.